# Get Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, sharedpreferences

I updated Xcode from version 13.4.1 to 14.3, when I run my flutter app the [exception appears in the `SharedPreferencesPlugin` on the call to `registrar.messenger()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K6Mg.png).

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

The package uses the following version specification:

```
   shared_preferences: ^2.0.12
```

Below is the log of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.0, on macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64, locale pt) • Flutter version 3.7.0 on channel stable at /Users/pedro/fvm/versions/3.7.0 • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git • Framework revision b06b8b2710 (3 months ago), 2023-01-23 16:55:55 -0800 • Engine revision b24591ed32 • Dart version 2.19.0 • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2) • Android SDK at /Users/pedro/Library/Android/sdk • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2 • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495) • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3) • Xcode at /Users/pedro/Downloads/Xcode 2.app/./Contents/Developer • Build 14E222b • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1) • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents • Flutter plugin can be installed from:  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter • Dart plugin can be installed from:  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1.4) • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app • Flutter plugin can be installed from:  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter • Dart plugin can be installed from:  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.0) • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents • Flutter extension version 3.62.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available) • iPhone 14 Pro (mobile) • CD024760-9AF2-42C8-B34D-C1F79D73141C • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-4 (simulator) • macOS (desktop) • macos • darwin-x64 • macOS 13.1 22C65 darwin-x64 • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.63

[✓] HTTP Host Availability • All required HTTP hosts are available
```